# Create executable and hide application code in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I created an application in Node.JS that sends data from a local MySQL database to a MondoDB database in a Cloud.

I want to install it on my clients without them seeing the source code and not even needing to have the Node.JS environment installed. Basically I want to turn it into an executable, as is done in Delphi, then the client would only have the executable and with that in theory it would not have access to my source code and would not even need the Node.JS environment installed, just the executable being enough.

I saw that this is possible using PKG at: https://devpleno.com/hands-on-pkg. But on the other hand I saw many threads on the subject saying that this is not effective, obfuscation techniques, but all aimed at JavaScript for the web, which is not my case, so I was worried.

In my studies on Node.JS all the examples I've seen are kept in production in the Node.JS environment with the code exposed, since they run on the server side and clients don't have access.

But in this case of distributing the app to customers, it made me think, and such doubts arose.

Does Node.JS see this? Is it best suited for this? Are there any more suitable options? Or JavaScript applications, even if they're not for the web, can't be turned into executables that actually hide the source code, and if they can't, why?